# execution in background and main thread ios

Tags: multithreading, ios, background, execution

I have a function foo() which is calling a function bar on a background thread
`foo()
{`

```
  [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(bar:) withObject:nil];
```

}

```
 bar()
{
//some initialsations
//calling another function
bar1();//also in background
 //after bar1() returns
 //marking following statement with *       
      [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopActivityIndicator:)withObject:nil     wailUntilDone:YES];

  }
```

bar() does some things before calling another function. All that bar() does is in the background. In the meanwhile, I am showing the ActivityIndicator. Once my function inside bar() returns, I am calling a function that will stopActivityIndicator on the MainThread.

Now, I want to do call another function in the MainThread before calling the stopActivityIndicator()
How do I do it?
Can I put another `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(functionIWantToCall:)withObject:nil wailUntilDone:YES];`
     before * ?

Answer (score 2):

You can dispatch a block to run on the main thread and put whatever code you need into that block:

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^ {

   // Code here
   NSLog(@"This is the main thread");

}];
```

Using your code, that'd become:

```
bar()
{
    bar1();

    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^ {
        [stopActivityIndidator];
        [functionIWant];
    }];
}
```